# delete repeat elements matlab

Tags: matlab, find, intersect

I have two matrices:

Input:

```
A = [1,1;2,4;3,9;4,16;5,25];
B = [3,9;4,16;6,26;7,49;5,25];
```

Output:

```
A = [1,1;2,4;3,9;4,16;5,25];
B = [6,26;7,49];
```

I want to delete the repeating elements of `A` from `B` or vice-versa. Below is my current approach, but although correct, it is quite slow.

```
clear all;
clc;

A = [1,1;2,4;3,9;4,16;5,25];
B = [3,9;4,16;6,26;7,49;5,25];

C = B; 
L = 0;
for ii = 1:length(A)
    for jj = 1:length(B)
        if A(ii,1)==B(jj,1) && A(ii,2)==B(jj,2)

            C(jj,1)=0; 
            C(jj,2)=0; 

            L = L+1;
        end       
    end    
end
L
[A B C]


B = zeros(L-1,2);
L = 1;
for ii = 1:length(C)
    if C(ii,1)~=0 && C(ii,2)~=0

        B(L,1) = C(ii,1);
        B(L,2)=  C(ii,2);

        L = L+1;
    end
end
B
```

Can I do it by using `find` command? or by using the `intersect` command ? 
Thank you all for your help. For an matrix having a single column or a single row I have been able to do it by using the `find` command or the `intersect` command.

Comment: I see that. yes it is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>> B(~ismember(B, A, 'rows'), :)
```

ans =

```
 6    26
 7    49
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve rows. You should use `B(~ismember(B, A, 'rows'), :)` instead.

Comment: ah OK, Thanks Eitan T. Would you like to edit the answer?

Answer (score 1):

try `intersect` and `setdiff` to achive this goal

Answer (score 1):

However you did it for a single column using `intersect(A,B)`, you should be able to do it for multiple columns using `intersect(A,B,'rows')`